# Can React detect a change made with jQuery over an attribute of a component?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a React component that is shared across a number of applications. These applications need to change a quality of the component (the class of some buttons) when a state changes in each application. But for some reason they all decided to do this using jQuery: changing the class of the buttons using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Now I need to detect the changes to these components according to their class, but I can't get it as a form of state change because that state isn't changed.

Can React detect when another actor modifies a DOM element that belongs to one of its components? My initial guess was "no" because React keeps track of a virtual DOM, not the "real" DOM over which these jQuery methods are being invoked. But I was hoping there was a way.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. React doesn't monitor the DOM for changes. jQuery and React are IMO very orthogonal to each in their approach to handling UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your situation you could use the [mutation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) along with React's [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to listen to class changes.

you likely create a mutation observer function, passing the Node and the callback handler:

```
const mutationObserver = (targetNode, handler) => {
  const config = { attributeFilter: ['class'] }; // filter the mutations you want to listen

  const callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        handler(mutation.oldValue);
    }
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  observer.observe(targetNode, config);
};
```

at your component you need the create a reference to pass down to mutation:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  myHandler = () => { // implement here logic to handle changes }

  componentDidMount() {
    mutationObserver(this.myRef.current, this.myHandler)
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} class="my-classes">my element to listen<div>
  }
}
```

you might consider creating a HOC for that, specially if this is gonna be applied to several components.